# Installing FIWARE Murano implementation in my FIWARE Lab node or OpenStack

Tags: fiware, fiware-murano

I would like to install the implemented version of Murano developed in FIWARE inside the FIWARE Lab node that I have configured. Is there anything special that I have to do? Can I install it in a OpenStack environment outside the FIWARE Lab node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Murano is an application catalogue service included in Openstack.
You can find some information about how to install Murano in http://murano.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install/. You could install Murano with the rest of your Openstack services or outside, it is up to you. The only consideration is that you should configure correctly the file /etc/murano/murano.conf with the Openstack infrastructure configurtion. For instance, you need to indicate the following configuration variables to connect to FIWARE Lab:

- auth_url = http://cloud.lab.fiware.org:4731/v2.0
- admin_password = admin password
- admin_tenant_name = admin
- admin_user = admin
- auth_uri = http://cloud.lab.fiware.org:4731/v2.0
- region_name_for_services = the default region to be connected